# Shopping cart with CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to do some kind of shopping cart with CakePHP 2 using arrays in cookies.

**What I have done:**

```
public $components = array('Cookie');

public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Cookie->name= ' order_cookie';
}
```

A button calls this function:

```
public function addOrder(){
    $this->Cookie->write('order_cookie', array(
        'order_id' => $order_id,
        'quantity' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['quantity'],
        'description' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['description'],
        'price' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['price']
    ));
}
```

I display the results in a view `order.ctp`. This is the `order` controller:

```
public function order(){
    $this->set('myorder', $this->Cookie->read('order_cookie'));
}
```

In the view `order.ctp`:

```
<table>             
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php
    if(isset($myorder)){
        foreach($myorder as $theorder){
            ?>            
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $theorder['order_id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $theorder['quantity'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $theorder['description'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $theorder['price'];?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

**I have two problems:**

1. When I add an order, it erases the previous order instead of adding a new one
2. When I display the results, it gives me in each rows and each lines a `Warning : Illegal string offset`

**What I want:**

I just want that when a customer adds an order, the programs adds the array in the cookie instead of erasing the previous and finally displays the results correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is how you are writing to your cookie. This method call in your `addOrder` function is overwriting your data each time it is called:-

```
$this->Cookie->write('order_cookie', array(
    'order_id' => $order_id,
    'quantity' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['quantity'],
    'description' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['description'],
    'price' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['price']
));
```

What you want to do is append the new data to `order_cookie`. You will need to first read the cookie data, then append to that before re-writing your cookie. For example:-

```
$orderCookie = $this->Cookie->read('order_cookie');

$orderCookie[] = array(
    'order_id' => $order_id,
    'quantity' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['quantity'],
    'description' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['description'],
    'price' => $this->request->data['addOrder']['price']
);

$orderCookie = $this->Cookie->write('order_cookie', $orderCookie);
```

`order_cookie` will now be a numerically indexed array of order details.